# How Do I Find the last value for each row in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

SQL Server 2008, as you can see in the data a program could have an actual date or a null (program is still open).

I want only the row with the last value (whether a date or a NULL) for each program for every program in the resultset.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
    RowNum ProgramKey PgmStartDate PgmEndDate
    ------------------------------------------
    2      1014       4/1/2005     2/28/2017
    4      1014       3/1/2017     NULL
    5      1015       3/1/2017     NULL
    3      1015       4/1/2005     2/28/2017
    6      1262       7/1/2017     NULL
    1      1262       1/1/2012     6/30/2017
```

I have tried `Top 1` but that only returns 1 row for the entire resultset.

I have tried `MAX(PgmEndDate)` but again only returns 1 row for the entire resultset.

`LAST_VALUE` works in SQL Server 2012 and newer but this configuration is SQL Server 2008 and will remain so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: In the case of the data shown: Only the most recent records as defined by the latest PgmEndDate with NULL being the most recent. In the data sample I expect 3 records.

Comment: "last value" as defined as the one with the highest (most recent) pgmStartDate per programKey?

Comment: most recent pgmEndDate

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select max(PgmEndDate), ProgramKey from table group by ProgramKey
```

Comment: Almost - it is ignoring the NULLs as most recent PgmEndDate.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `ISNULL` to use a very high default. This will allow you to sort your dates including `NULL` values, which will be ranked highest:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(RowNum INT,ProgramKey INT,PgmEndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (2,1014,'2/28/2017')
,(4,1014,NULL)
,(5,1015,NULL)
,(3,1015,'2/28/2017')
,(6,1262,NULL);
```

--Get a rank, which you might use for further filtering

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.ProgramKey ORDER BY ISNULL(PgmEndDate,{d'2999-01-01'}) DESC) AS SortKey
      ,m.* 
FROM @mockup AS m
```

--or get the `MAX()`. In this case I use `NULLIF` to get the `NULL`s back

```
SELECT NULLIF(MAX(ISNULL(PgmEndDate,{d'2999-01-01'})),{d'2999-01-01'}),m.ProgramKey
FROM @mockup AS m
GROUP BY m.ProgramKey
```

Comment: It gets the NULLs but doesnt select the last value. i am trying to mimic  LAST_VALUE form MSSQL2012 and higher

Comment: @BobParis What is the *last value*? The *last* value is always depeding on some kind of a sort order but there is no implict sort order in SQL Server's tables. The result might be random. Use the ranking approach from above and add the RowNum to the `ORDER BY` withing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`.

Comment: @BobParis Please use the edit option at your question to add some more rows to the test data and state your expected output explicitly (fitting to the given test data)

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean you want nulls to be a picked before other date values.  How to handle ties isn't explained so I made some assumptions.

- Show only records for each programKey whose endDate is null.
- In the absence of a null endDate; show the record with the most recent endDate for a programkey
- If multiple records have a null endDate for a program key or the same value, pick the one with the most recent pgmStartDate,
- if multiple records for a programKey have the same pgmEndDate and StartDate, display the record with the earliest RowNum

We basically say for each ProgramKey, order by null endDates first, then by endDates, then by startDates, then by row number.  that way, we can't have a tie.

http://rextester.com/AGJP44270

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
           , RowN = Row_Number() over (PARTITION BY ProgramKey 
                                       ORDER BY case when pgmEndDate is null then 0 else 1 end
                                              , pgmEndDate desc
                                              , pgmStartDate desc
                                              , rownum) 
      FROM cte) a
WHERE a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Tested it against the data. Its history for the last year (for example). This code returns all the records with NULLS.  I am looking for the most recent record for the program whether the program is open or not. If its still open then the row with the most recent PgmStartDate with the NULL in the PgmEndDate. If the program is not open then I want the most recent row with the most recent PgmStartDate with itsPgmEndDate.

Comment: Updated.  you've not explained how you want ties to happen if a programkey has multiple null end dates or two are show as "most recent" for a key.  but maybe that situation can't occur.

Comment: @BobParis  made some assumptions on how to handle ties and added some sample test data. http://rextester.com/QNT39834

Answer (score 0):

Try this (sqlserver 2008 +). I used the date '2200-01-01'   As the replacement for null dates to get the null date value as the maximum date

```
With programData as(
Select ProgramKey , pgmStartData, pgmEndDate 
, row_number() over ( partition by programKey order by isnull(pgmEndDate,'2200-01-01')  Desc)rowNumDesc
From yourtable
)
Select * from programData
 Where rowNumDesc=1
```